# Rust compound declaration

Tags: rust

In C you can delcare a bunch of similar variables at once:

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3;
```

How would you do this in rust? I can do something like:

```
let (mut a, mut b, mut c) = (1i, 2i, 3i);
```

But this requires stating `mut` and `i` multiple times. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: It almost always looks nicer to write `let mut a = 1i;` `let mut b = 2i;` `let mut c = 3i;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a shorter way to do this.

---

Well, that's not quite true. You could define [a macro](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/guide-macros.html):

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! multi_mut_let {
    ( $( $id: ident = $value: expr ),* ) => {
        let ( $( mut $id, )* ) = ($( $value, )*);
    }
}

fn main() {
    multi_mut_let!(a = 1i, b = 2u, c = 3f64);

    a += 1;
    b *= 2;
    c -= 3.0;
    println!("{} {} {}", a, b, c); // 2 4 0

    // edge cases (which are handled fine):
    multi_mut_let!();
    multi_mut_let!(_x = 2u);
}
```

Those with sharp eyes will notice the comma is placed slightly strangely in the RHS of the macro expansion, since it results in a trailing comma on both sides of the `let`. This allows the second edge case to be handled correctly. Without the trailing comma, it expands to `let (mut _x) = (2u);`, but [parens like that are not (yet) allowed in patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11144); with the trailing comma it expands to `let (mut _x,) = (2u,);`, which are 1-tuples, and so the pattern matching is fine.